# How do I make my application display whatever drag graphic is used by the source?

Tags: windows, drag-and-drop

When you drag a picture from Firefox to Windows Explorer, Explorer shows Firefox's drag graphic. How does he do it?

Illustration: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rliNPuKh58 (The video capture is not entirely accurate - the mouse cursor is shown as an arrow at all times when it in fact changes between the default drag and drop cursor and the slashed circle.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh, sorry.  I only gave it a quick glance.  You'll have to use the shell COM interfaces (IDropSource, IDragSourceHelper) to achieve this.